# MVC asp.net No ViewData item of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to asp.net MVC.  I am writing an application that will allow system administrators to view/edit/add a list of servers. I already have the database of servers, so I used database first to create an entity framework model.

From here, I used Visual Studios auto-generation to create a couple views.  The first one worked magically and really showed me the power of this framework as it resolved all foreign key lookups without any work on my part in terms of joining tables.

For the second, I used Visual Studio to generated a Create view.  I then created a Create [HttpGet] function that simply returns a new object.  However, when I click this link - the application explodes on these lines of code:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServerOS, "ServerOS", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ServerOS", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServerOS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

The above code was generated by visual studio when I created the view for the model.  It gives me the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 
'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ServerOS'.
```

The action for the view is as follows:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View("Create", 
            new SQLServer());
    }
```

I should note that ServerOS is a foreign key in the database.  I am also very new to HTML so I am having a tough time reading what it is doing.

Comment: Because `ServerOS` is not `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` You need to generate a `SelectList` in the controller and pass it to the view (a dropdownlist required 2 values - the property to bind to (the selected value) and a property for the collection of options (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) fro an explanation)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you very much! I'll edit my post with the answer, unless you want to post yours as an answer.

Comment: Feel fee to add your own answer (make it an answer not an edit to the question so you can accept it and close this out)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I thought the magic of asp.net mvc was stronger than it was, of course I had to specify the list.  Stephen Muecke pointed out that I needed to generate a select list in the controller and pass it to the view.  For those who search this question, the code was fixed by adding these lines of code in the controller:

```
var OSListQuery = (from version in _ServerDB.Versions select version).ToList();
ViewBag.ServerOS = new SelectList(OSListQuery, "VersionID", "Version1");
```

Where VersionID is the name of the data variable in the query list, and Version1 is the name of the text I wanted to display in the query list.

Comment: This can cause other problems because the name of the `SelectList` is the same as the name of the property. Use `ViewBag.ServerOSList = new SelectList(...)` and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ServerOS, (SelectList)ViewBag.ServerOSList, ....)`

Comment: Thanks :) That makes sense